# chapter title on header and not subchapter

Tags: header-footer

Hello I'm trying to use for header only the chapter title and not the sections or subsections but none of the posts that i have found helped, I'm not sure if and how i can change that, that's why I upload the following example. I hope that someone can help, thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[
% Replace twoside with oneside if you are printing your thesis on a single side
% of the paper, or for viewing on screen.
%oneside,
oneside,
11pt, a4paper,
footinclude=true,
headinclude=true,
cleardoublepage=empty
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{0.25in}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
\setlength{\cftbeforetabskip}{0.2in}

\title{Thesis Title}
\author{John Doe}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures 
\listoftables 

\chapter{Acknowledgements} 

I would like to thank my supervisor, Professor Someone. This 
research was funded by the Imaginary Research Council. 

\chapter{Abstract} 

A brief summary of the project goes here. 

\chapter{Abbreviations}

\mainmatter 

\include{intro2} 

\backmatter  

\begin{thebibliography}{100} % 100 is a random guess of the total number of 
 %references 
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

and for the intro2.tex:

```
\chapter{Introduction} 
\label{ch:intro} 
\section{Blabal}

blaalblbla
\subsection{blubl} 
blublbu
```

Comment: How about just adding `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}` to your preamble?

Comment: thanks a lot, this worked! Do you know if it is also possible to appear the number of the chapter along with the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without too much hassle it seems sufficient to add the following to the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\thechapter~#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\thechapter~#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}%
```

`\chaptermark` is updated to insert `\thechapter` before the chapter title as part of the header, while `\sectionmark` is made into a macro that only gobbles its argument (thereby doing nothing).